# counting the new line in file using c

Tags: c, counting

For the text: `Hi\r\n how is it going \r\nareyouoay\r\n` ; the answer should be 3, the new line **does not mean** `\n` it means strictly `\r\n`, so just having `\n` is not good

Here is my attempt, what am i doing wrong?

```
FILE  *fp = fopen(fileName, "r"); 
int c, lastchar;           
int lineCount= 0;
int i;

while ( (c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) {
    if ( c == 'r' && lastchar == '\\' && c+1== '\\' && c+2=='n')
        lineCount++;
    lastchar = c; 
    i++;
}
```

the output should be 3 for that text.

Comment: In your text, \n means two characters '\' and 'n' concatened, or it is meaning the single character '\n' (ascii 10)?

Comment: What is the answer for "Hi\nHow\r\nare\ryou\r\n"

Comment: @user1888502 Are you on Windows? If yes, you probably want to open your file with `fopen(fileName, "rb")` to open the file in binary mode, otherwise the `\r` characters will be removed from the string by the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you must do your search character at a time, you could use something like the following code

```
int c;           
int lineCount= 0;
int i = 0;
char next[] = {'\\', 'r', '\\', 'n' };
while ( (c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) {
    if (c != next[i]) {
        i = 0;
    }
    else {
        if (i == sizeof(next) - 1) {
            i = 0;
            lineCount++;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

For bounded input file sizes, you'd be better off reading the whole file into memory then using [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) instead.  Or, for larger inputs, read chunks into memory, use `strstr` and consider how to avoid missing matches on chunk boundaries.

Comment: just '\n' will work too

Comment: thats not what I want to do, I want to specifically count the \r\n and count that as one while its in the string, so if a single line has Hi\r\n how is it going \r\nareyouoay\r\n  the output should be 3, even though its all on one line. To do that, I need to read each char and make sure all of them occur.

Comment: @simonc that please read the above

Comment: @user1888502 I've updated my answer now.  Note that if two answers both misunderstand your question in the same way, it probably means the question should have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is, `\n` is 1 character, not multiple characters.

Hence to count the number of lines you gotta do this:

```
while ((c = fgetc(fp))!= EOF){
   if(c == '\n') lineCount++;
}

printf("No. of lines = %d", lineCount);
```

Comment: thats not what I want to do, I want to specifically count the \r\n and count that as one while its in the string, so if a single line has Hi\r\n how is it going \r\nareyouoay\r\n  the output should be 3, even though its all on one line. To do that, I need to read each char and make sure all of them occur. The way to count a line is NOT by \n in my approach, a line is represented by \r\n all together, just \n will be text but if a user has \r\n then it means new line

Answer (score 0):

The characters `\r` and `\n` are single characters, so when reading your input, you won't find `\\` characters in them. Moreover, if you are on Windows, you should open your file with mode `"rb"` to open it in binary mode, otherwise the runtime will strip the `\r` characters.

```
FILE  *fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
int lastchar = 0;
int lineCount = 0;
int c;

while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (lastchar == '\r' && c == '\n')
        lineCount++;
    lastchar = c;
}

printf("line count: %d\n", lineCount);
```

If you really want to count the succession of the four characters `\\` `r` `\\` `n`, then you can do it that way (seems odd, but maybe your input has quoted characters sequences in it):

```
FILE  *fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
char prevchars[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
char fingerprint[4] = { '\\', 'r', '\\', 'n' };
int lineCount = 0;
int c, i;

while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    if (memcmp(prevchars, fingerprint, 4) == 0)
        lineCount++;
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        prevchars[i - 1] = prevchars[i];
    prevchars[3] = (char)c;
}

printf("line count: %d\n", lineCount);
```

Comment: This should be a correct answer but the question is trying to ask how to search for `"\\r\\n"`  i.e. 4 separate chars.  Both other answers took the same approach as yours so the question isn't as clear as it could be.